# Insert if not exists: SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, android-sqlite

I want to insert data if that headline doesn't exist yet in the database.

This is the error I'm getting for the written query:

> near "with": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM movie WHERE headline=Albert Collen

Code:

```
public boolean Insert(Item item) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE headline=" + item.getName() , null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    } else {
        contentValues.put("name", item.getName());           
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi ghazalia. can post what's the value for "name" parameter? Can it contain non-letter characters?

Comment: Hi. name is a string. does it matter what the string value is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use query parameters

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE headline = ?", new String[] {"Albert Collen"});
```

to avoid having to escape quotes and other chars.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, result query is wrong. All the string constants are to be quoted, like this

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE headline='Albert Collen';
```

So, try to compose query like this, perhaps it will help

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE headline='" + item.getName() + "'" , null);
```

But concatenating a query is not a good idea because it makes at least SQL-injections possible.

For example, it can cause problems when item.getName() contains following line "'; drop table movies;"

Better option would be using bind query variables. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with how to use java-android with sqlite, so it is better for you to check how to use such a queries in android

Comment: thank you. but what if the name had an ' ? for example if the name was The Queen's Gambit ?@ekochergin

Comment: @ghazalia it will also cause query to fail because of the way how you're composing the query. And I am sure it won't fail if you decided to use query with bind variables. Another way to avoid this particular case would be to double each quote, so it the "Queen's Gambit" will be converted to "Queen''s Gambit". Note this is not double-quotes (") but two single-quotes ('')